# Is it possible to change Java syntax within a project?

Tags: java, syntax

Is there a way to define custom syntax for a given Java project?

For example, one thing I would like to be able to do would be to essentially create a short-hand syntax for standard getters and setters (similar to .NET's "{ get; set; }"). As I've been searching, all I've come across is that writing a DSL might be able to accomplish this, but as I was looking into them, I don't know that they would suit the need.

So is there any way to define extra syntactical elements like this?

Comment: You would have to implement a custom parser.

Comment: You're looking for Scala.

Comment: @HighCore, Scala is built on JVM so he can reuse existing code.

Comment: @HighCore I don't think the OP is looking for a complete toolchain change, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since others have established that changing the syntax is not really possible, you might be interested in [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/).

From the Getting Started guide:

```
private boolean employed = true;
private String name;

public boolean isEmployed() {
    return employed;
}

public void setEmployed(final boolean employed) {
    this.employed = employed;
}

protected void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

becomes

```
@Getter @Setter private boolean employed = true;
@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED) private String name;
```

Comment: Tried it and seems to live up to it's promises :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this.

The Java compiler parses Java code using the syntax defined in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).

If you want to use non-Java syntax to write a program compilable with the Java compiler, you will have to use/create a tool that can take your syntax and transform it to valid Java (this type of transformation falls under the category generally referred to as "preprocessing").

Keep in mind that if you do create a preprocessor, it adds one more thing to the list of things you need to maintain and document, which is especially important for larger/team projects.

Comment: I recall working on a project in the past where we used a custom code generation tool that generated both the documentation of and framework for an AJAX-style API (it spit out Java, a JavaScript library, and formatted documentation). However, looking back, there were better solutions, and, while convenient, it was more a reinvention of the wheel than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, at least not without using external tools.

And it is not a good idea. Other sw developpers who join the company/project in future should be able to read the source as standard java.